# Orchard CMS - How to bind an Enumeration Field in a Dynamic Form?

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I've created a Enumeration Field in a dynamic form and want to bind the value to the Content when I submit it, however when I setup the enumeration field it does not have a Binding Tab unlike the other Fields.

When I submit the form the value doesn't seem to bind correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but when I added another Enumeration Field that one had a binding tab, then that one worked fine.

Might be some bug when you import content from another site as that is how that enumeration field was created.